# Error in Outer Joins - Joining date with date

Tags: sql, oracle

I used the code below to create table#1;

```
SELECT a.DMT_MONTH, a.PRODUCT_CATEGORY, a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, SUM(a.OUTPUT)
FROM OUTPUT_TABLE a
  INNER JOIN CATEGORY b 
    ON a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = b.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
    AND b.CATEGORY_SET_NAME = 'INVENTORY'
GROUP BY a.DMT_MONTH, a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, a.PRODUCT_CATEGORY;
```

Table#1;

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
| DMT_MONTH | PRODUCT_CATEGORY | INVENTORY_ITEM_ID | OUTPUT |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
| May-19    | Mouse            |              5648 |     50 |
| JUN-19    | Mouse            |              5648 |   1000 |
| May-19    | Keyboard         |              5646 |     20 |
| May-19    | Monitor          |              5689 |     10 |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

I have another table, Table#2;

```
+---------------+---------+----------+
| CREATION_DATE | ITEM_ID | ISSUE_NO |
+---------------+---------+----------+
| 02/May/19     |    5648 | A1       |
| 15/May/19     |    5648 | A4       |
| 23/Jun/19     |    5646 | A8       |
+---------------+---------+----------+
```

**END RESULT**

I would like to outer join the table i have created (Table#1) into Table#2. Final table output would be similar to below;

```
+---------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+----------+
| CREATION_DATE | CREATION_DATE#2 | DMT_MONTH | PRODUCT_CATEGORY | INVENTORY_ITEM_ID | OUTPUT | ISSUE_NO |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+----------+
| 02/May/19     | May-19          | May-19    | Mouse            |              5648 |     50 | A1       |
| 15/May/19     | May-19          | May-19    | Mouse            |              5648 |     50 | A4       |
| 23/Jun/19     | Jun-19          | Jun-19    | Keyboard         |              5646 |     20 | A8       |
|               |                 | Jun-19    | Mouse            |              5648 |     50 |          |
|               |                 | May-19    | Monitor          |              5689 |     10 |          |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+----------+
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR**

Please excuse the formatting of the code below

```
Select d.CREATION_DATE,
  TO_CHAR(d.CREATION_DATE, 'MON-YY'),
  d.RES_INCIDENT_NUMBER ,
  d.ITEM_ID
From RAPIDVIEW.NCP_INCIDENT d
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT a.DMT_MONTH, a.PRODUCT_CATEGORY, a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, SUM(a.OUTPUT)
    FROM OUTPUT_TABLE a
    INNER JOIN CATEGORY b 
     ON a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = b.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
     AND b.CATEGORY_SET_NAME = 'INVENTORY'
    GROUP BY a.DMT_MONTH, a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, a.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
  ) c
ON (c.DMT_MONTH = d.TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'MON-YY')) AND (c.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = d.ITEM_ID);
```

To join DMT_MONTH with CREATION_DATE, I tried creating an extra column TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'MON-YY') to allow me to join them together. Unfortunately I keep getting this error below;

```
ORA-00904: "D"."TO_CHAR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 77 Column: 19
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated. I would to use the final output in tableau to analyse.

Comment: `d.TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE` --->  `TO_CHAR(d.CREATION_DATE`  *qualify columns not functions*

Comment: Thank you for quick reply Marmite, however i have modified the code to d.TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE ....), however i am still getting the same error.

Comment: @ARJ I think you modified the wrong line? you should have changed `c.DMT_MONTH = d.TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'MON-YY')` to `c.DMT_MONTH = TO_CHAR(d.CREATION_DATE, 'MON-YY')`

Comment: Thanks Nick, i made a few changes in accordance yours and Marmite's suggestion and managed to figure out the answer. Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to understand what i was doing wrong. The date outer join was not in the correct format. Please see code below;

```
ON (c.DMT_MONTH = d.TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'Mon-YY')) AND (c.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = d.ITEM_ID);
```